# how to access currently lasso or selected points in Plotly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js, retool

I am making a lasso select or box select tool of this 96 grid

[image]

I want to be able to access the currently highlighted wells in Retool via `customComponent.model.selectedPoints`

The current plotly code is:

```js
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.tryretool.com/js/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tryretool.com/js/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script src="   https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-plotly.js@latest/dist/create-plotly-component.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div id="react" />
<script type="text/babel">
    const Plot = createPlotlyComponent.default(Plotly);
  console.log(Plot);
  

  const MyCustomComponent = ({ triggerQuery, model, modelUpdate }) => (
      <Plot
        data={[
          {
            x: model.plotData.x,
            y: model.plotData.y,
            text: model.plotData.well,
            hoverinfo: 'text',
            mode: 'markers',
            type: 'scatter',
            marker: {color: 'blue', size: 20, opacity: 0.7},
          }
        ]}
        onClick={(v) => {
                    modelUpdate({ clickedPoint: v.points.map(p => ({ x: p.x, y: p.y, well: p.text })) })
        }}
        layout={ {title: 'Well Selector', 
        xaxis: {showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    showline: false,
        side: 'top',
      fixedrange: true,
      tickvals:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                ticktext: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]},
        yaxis: {showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    showline: false,
      fixedrange: true,
      tickvals:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                ticktext: ['H','G','F','E','D','C','B','A']} } }
        style={ {width: "100%", height: "100%"} }
      />
  );

  const ConnectedComponent = Retool.connectReactComponent(MyCustomComponent);
  ReactDOM.render(<ConnectedComponent />, document.getElementById("react"));
</script>
```

You can see it partially working below but it only shows the selectedPoints which is based on onClick (it only returns a single point at the moment because of the .map method), specifically I need to edit line somehow

```js
onClick={(v) => {
    modelUpdate({ clickedPoint: v.points.map(p => ({ x: p.x, y: p.y, well: p.text })) })
        }}
```

... to the right JS syntax to return all the highlighted objects (either by lasso or box select from the Plotly model but I don't know what the variable/syntax is).

Essentially something like this:

```js
onSelected={(v) => { 
                    modelUpdate({ selectedPoints: v.points.text })
        }}
```

My understanding is that there is a Plotly scatter selectedPoints objects, but I'm unsure how to access that in the JS above to add that object to the model.

[image]

**Update**

I simply added

```
onSelected={(v) => { 
                    modelUpdate({ selectedPoints: v.points.map(p => p.text) })
        }
```

Now I can access selectedPoints in the component.model.selectedPoints only trouble is the lasso highlight colour doesn’t persist as soon as I unclick the lasso and I have to click lasso every time (I think I’m overwriting the `onSelected` function plotly uses internally)

Comment: Take those points, save them to state, then create a plotly shape object out of them pass them to the layout.shapes prop. Unfortunately there is no selectionLasso prop or anything like that that allows you to control the selection boxes or lasso.